# Expectation of Maximum and Minimum of Partial Sums of Normal Random Variables

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, extreme-value, sum

Peggy Strait, 1974, [Pacific Journal of Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Journal_of_Mathematics)

[ON THE MAXIMUM AND MINIMUM OF PARTIAL SUMS OF RANDOM VARIABLES](https://msp.org/pjm/1974/52-2/pjm-v52-n2-p27-p.pdf)

Gives a nice result (4.3) and (4.4) in terms of "standard normal random variables".

$ S_k = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=k} X_n $
when $[X_n] \approx\mathcal{N}(\mu=0,\sigma^2=1)$
and $ k \in [1 ... N] $

(4.3) $E[max(S_k)] = + {1 \over \sqrt{2 \pi}} 
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N-1} {1 \over \sqrt{k}}$

(4.4) $E[min(S_k)] = - {1 \over \sqrt{2 \pi}} 
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N-1} {1 \over \sqrt{k}}$

Instead, what would be that result expressed in closed form with explicit $\mu$ and $\sigma$ ?

$S_k=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=k} {X_n}$
when $[X_n] \approx\mathcal{N}(\mu \not=0,\sigma^2 \not= 1)$

(4.3) $E[max(S_k)] = ...?$

(4.4) $E[min(S_k)] = ...?$

Comment: Links can go bad, so please type the relevant contents into the question itself. Are you familiar with what the standard normal distribution is?

Comment: updated, please review, thank you.

Comment: Changing $\mu,\sigma$ is tantamount to re-expressing all values in different units of measurement (think of changing between degrees F and degrees C): the answer is immediate.

Comment: well, the logic in the original paper by P. Strait https://msp.org/pjm/1974/52-2/pjm-v52-n2-p27-p.pdf is non-parametric, and the logic of her reference paper by J. McFadden https://www.jstor.org/stable/3212025?seq=1 is inaccessible, so the answer is not immediate, for me :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One form of a "closed form" is an algorithm. Here is a [reference implementation in python](https://gist.github.com/Andrei-Pozolotin/302de66d70abc50a62c37cfb46b1c93d).